# ignoring second debugger and service hang in android

Tags: android, debugging

hi as i run my app my services r running but after some time a msg comes
ignoring second debugger- accepting and dropping  continuously and my service got hanged.
plz help. my file is following

```
D/PackageManager(   58):   Receivers: com.company.cellSafetyZone.controller.IncomingCallReceiver com.company.cellSafetyZone.controller.LocationReceiver com.company.cellSafetyZone.controller.OutGoingCallReceiver com.company.cellSafetyZone.controller.InComingSmsReceiver com.company.cellSafetyZone.controller.InComingMmsReceiver com.company.cellSafetyZone.controller.OutGoingSmsReceiver
D/PackageManager(   58):   Activities: com.company.cellSafetyZone.view.SplashScreen
I/installd(   34): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.company.cellSafetyZone-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.company.cellSafetyZone-2.apk@classes.dex
D/PackageManager(   58): New package installed in /data/app/com.company.cellSafetyZone-2.apk
D/dalvikvm(  128): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11288 objects / 558632 bytes in 83ms
I/ActivityManager(   58): Force stopping package com.company.cellSafetyZone uid=10032
I/ActivityManager(   58): Force stopping package com.company.cellSafetyZone uid=10032
D/Exchange(  242): BootReceiver onReceive
I/ActivityManager(   58): Start proc com.company.cellSafetyZone for broadcast com.company.cellSafetyZone/.controller.LocationReceiver: pid=256 uid=10032 gids={3003, 1015}
D/EAS SyncManager(  242): !!! EAS SyncManager, onCreate
D/EAS SyncManager(  242): !!! EAS SyncManager, onStartCommand
D/dalvikvm(   58): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6262 objects / 414352 bytes in 179ms
D/EAS SyncManager(  242): !!! EAS SyncManager, stopping self
D/Loction Receiver(  256): IN Location Service...
D/Loction Receiver(  256): received unexpected intent...Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED cmp=com.company.cellSafetyZone/.controller.LocationReceiver }
D/CheckLocation(  256): onCreate()
D/MediaScannerService(  216): done scanning volume internal
D/CheckLocation(  256): startService()
D/CheckLocation(  256): 1
D/CheckLocation(  256): 2
D/CheckLocation(  256): 3
D/OUT GOING SMS RECEIVER(  256): IN Outgoing sms receiver...
D/OUT GOING SMS RECEIVER(  256): received unexpected intent...Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED cmp=com.company.cellSafetyZone/.controller.OutGoingSmsReceiver }
D/SMS SERVICE(  256): blank constructor
D/SMS SERVICE(  256): in on Create() of sms service
D/SMS SERVICE(  256): calling service
D/SMS SERVICE(  256): registering resolver
D/SMS SERVICE(  256): registering observer
D/SMS SERVICE(  256): registerd
I/ActivityManager(   58): Force stopping package com.company.cellSafetyZone uid=10032
D/Eas Debug(  242): Logging: 
W/ActivityManager(   58): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.company.cellSafetyZone/.model.OutGoingSmsService in 5000ms
W/ActivityManager(   58): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.company.cellSafetyZone/.model.CheckLocation in 14999ms
I/Process (   58): Sending signal. PID: 256 SIG: 9
I/WindowManager(   58): WIN DEATH: Window{43f2efc8 Toast paused=false}
W/GpsLocationProvider(   58): Unneeded remove listener for uid 1000
I/ActivityManager(   58):   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{43ffc040 com.company.cellSafetyZone/.model.OutGoingSmsService}
I/ActivityManager(   58):   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{4400da20 com.company.cellSafetyZone/.model.CheckLocation}
D/EAS SyncManager(  242): !!! EAS SyncManager, onDestroy
D/dalvikvm(  164): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4102 objects / 253968 bytes in 333ms
W/RecognitionManagerService(   58): no available voice recognition services found
D/dalvikvm(   58): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3955 objects / 219648 bytes in 128ms
I/installd(   34): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.company.cellSafetyZone-1.apk@classes.dex
D/AndroidRuntime(  116): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm(  116): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
I/AndroidRuntime(  116): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
I/ActivityManager(   58): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=270 uid=10028 gids={}
I/ActivityThread(  270): Publishing provider com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider
D/AndroidRuntime(  269): 
D/AndroidRuntime(  269): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(  269): CheckJNI is ON
W/NotificationService(   58): Object died trying to hide notification android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@43face50 in package com.company.cellSafetyZone
W/ActivityManager(   58): setProcessForeground called on unknown pid: 256
D/AndroidRuntime(  269): --- registering native functions ---
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.company.cellSafetyZone/.view.SplashScreen }
D/AndroidRuntime(  269): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm(  269): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
I/AndroidRuntime(  269): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
I/ActivityManager(   58): Start proc com.company.cellSafetyZone for activity com.company.cellSafetyZone/.view.SplashScreen: pid=283 uid=10032 gids={3003, 1015}
I/jdwp    (  119): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/jdwp    (  123): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/jdwp    (  128): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/jdwp    (  130): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/jdwp    (  200): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/jdwp    (  242): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/jdwp    (  283): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/jdwp    (  270): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/jdwp    (  164): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/jdwp    (  171): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/jdwp    (  181): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/jdwp    (  189): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/jdwp    (  209): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/jdwp    (  216): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/jdwp    (  226): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
I/ActivityManager(   58): Displayed activity com.company.cellSafetyZone/.view.SplashScreen: 1222 ms (total 32701 ms)
I/ActivityManager(   58): Displayed activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: 32703 ms (total 32703 ms)
D/KeyguardViewMediator(   58): pokeWakelock(5000)
D/KeyguardViewMediator(   58): pokeWakelock(5000)
I/ARMAssembler(   58): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000004_00000000 [ 47 ipp] (67 ins) at [0x2fb598:0x2fb6a4] in 1489348 ns
I/ARMAssembler(   58): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x2fb6a8:0x2fb870] in 951160 ns
W/KeyCharacterMap(  283): No keyboard for id 0
W/KeyCharacterMap(  283): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
D/dalvikvm(  283): GC_EXPLICIT freed 854 objects / 59728 bytes in 182ms
D/SntpClient(   58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
D/AndroidRuntime(  304): 
D/AndroidRuntime(  304): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(  304): CheckJNI is ON
D/AndroidRuntime(  304): --- registering native functions ---
I/jdwp    (  304): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
D/AndroidRuntime(  304): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm(  304): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
I/AndroidRuntime(  304): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
D/AndroidRuntime(  322): 
D/AndroidRuntime(  322): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(  322): CheckJNI is ON
D/AndroidRuntime(  322): --- registering native functions ---
I/jdwp    (  322): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
D/AndroidRuntime(  322): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm(  322): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
I/AndroidRuntime(  322): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
D/AndroidRuntime(  334): 
D/AndroidRuntime(  334): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(  334): CheckJNI is ON
D/AndroidRuntime(  334): --- registering native functions ---
I/jdwp    (  334): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
D/AndroidRuntime(  334): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm(  334): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
I/AndroidRuntime(  334): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
D/AndroidRuntime(  344): 
D/AndroidRuntime(  344): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(  344): CheckJNI is ON
D/AndroidRuntime(  344): --- registering native functions ---
I/jdwp    (  344): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
D/AndroidRuntime(  344): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm(  344): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
I/AndroidRuntime(  344): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
D/SntpClient(   58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
D/SntpClient(   58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
D/dalvikvm(  119): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  123): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  128): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  130): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  283): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  164): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  171): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  189): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  200): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  209): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  216): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  270): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  242): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  226): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/dalvikvm(  181): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
```

Comment: format your post please!

Comment: what is this...realy ?!!

Answer (score 16):

It means you have two copies of DDMS (or the Eclipse ADT plugin) running simultaneously, and they're stepping on each other.

Comment: how could i check this?? can u tell me

Comment: by default, eclipse ADT plugin will have DDMS. Also, we can run manually DDMS through android platform tool "monitor"

Comment: @Partha How do we stop this then? This error pops up for me no matter what I try.

Comment: Or, one copy of DDMS plus the debugger in Android Studio, stepping on each other.

Comment: Worked for me ! Do you have to kill the second DDMS that is not used or is there a way to disconnect it without killing it?

Comment: Legend, forgot I had DDMS running in the background from earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting and creating another AVD solved this problem for me